# How to handle daylight savings in cron jobs

Tags: cron, crontab, time-zone

I have a cron job on an amazon ec2 machine (Ubuntu 16.04) that is supposed to run at 2:00 AM Central time.

The cron job is scheduled using UTC time. Since Central time is currently UTC-5 (we are in daylight savings time at the moment), it looks like this:

```
0 7 * * * /home/ubuntu/runetl.sh
```

So it runs at 7:00 AM UTC, which is correct.

But when we go back to standard time, Central will change to UTC-6, so the job will start running at 1:00 AM Central time. That's not what I want. I want them always to run at 2:00 AM regardless of daylight or standard time.

How can I do that?

Comment: Since UTC does not observe Daylight Saving Time, the simplest solution, is to set your system's timezone UTC.  This means it will always run at 7 AM UTC.  Depending on the time of the year, the job might run at 3 AM CST or 2 AM CST, but it will always run at 7 AM UTC.

Answer (score 3):

Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and set local time zone (instead of UTC) you needed.
Also setup and run `ntp` daemon that will synchronize time precisely and will switch between daytime saving time automatically gradually smoothly that is very important for time critical task as billing, email servers.

Comment: Thank you - it worked well. Seems appropriate for anyone who is concerned about factoring in daylight savings time on a scheduled job. Makes a big difference.